# Что делают эти строчки?

Tags: python, tkinter

Это только та часть кода, в которой я не понимаю и хочу разобраться. **Сколько бы я не искал в инете и ютубе, всё как-то не так объясняют.**

```
class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
    super(Main, self).__init__(root)
    self.startUI()
```

**ВЕСЬ КОД (ЕСЛИ НАДО)**

```
from tkinter import *
import random as rdm
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Main(Frame): 

    def __init__(self, root):                                           
    super(Main, self).__init__(root)   
                                           
    self.startUI()

    def startUI(self):
        btn = Button(root, text="Камень", font=("Times New Roman", 15),
                     command=lambda x=1: self.btn_click(x))
        btn2 = Button(root, text="Ножницы", font=("Times New Roman", 15),
                      command=lambda x=2: self.btn_click(x))
        btn3 = Button(root, text="Бумага", font=("Times New Roman", 15),
                      command=lambda x=3: self.btn_click(x))

        btn.place(x=10, y=100, width=120, height=50)
        btn2.place(x=155, y=100, width=120, height=50)
        btn3.place(x=300, y=100, width=120, height=50)

        self.lbl = Label(root, text="Начало игры!", bg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 20, "bold"))
        self.lbl.place(x=150, y=25)

        self.win = self.drow = self.lose = 0

        self.lbl2 = Label(root, justify="left", font=("Times New Roman", 13),
                         text=f"Побед: {self.win}\nПроигрышей:"
                              f" {self.lose}\nНичей: {self.drow}",
                         bg="#FFF")
        self.lbl2.place(x=5, y=5)
        
# +++
        self.imgLabel = Label(root)    
        self.imgLabel.place(x=330, y=20, width=50, height=50)

    def btn_click(self, choise):
        comp_choise = rdm.randint(1, 3)

        if choise == comp_choise:
            self.drow += 1
            self.lbl.configure(text="Ничья")

            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:\PYTHON\QUIZ\XZ.jpg"))
            self.imgLabel.configure(image=img)
            self.imgLabel.image = img  
  
        elif choise == 1 and comp_choise == 2 \
                or choise == 2 and comp_choise == 3 \
                or choise == 3 and comp_choise == 1:
            self.win += 1
            self.lbl.configure(text="Победа")
          
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:\PYTHON\QUIZ\Win.jpg"))
            self.imgLabel.configure(image=img)
            self.imgLabel.image = img  
        else:
            self.lose += 1
            self.lbl.configure(text="Проигрыш")

            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("E:\PYTHON\QUIZ\LOSE.jpg"))
            self.imgLabel.configure(image=img)
            self.imgLabel.image = img  
            
        self.lbl2.configure(text=f"Побед: {self.win}\nПроигрышей:"
                              f" {self.lose}\nНичей: {self.drow}")

        del comp_choise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("430x160+200+200")
    root.title("Камень, ножницы, бумага")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root["bg"] = "#FFF"
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь создаётся класс, с наследованием от `Frame`(т.е. создаётся свой(кастомный) Frame, который можно будет использовать как и обычный, но при создании он уже будет заполнен тем, что вы напишете. Потом определяется метод `__init__`, который вызывается когда вы создаёте объект класса. Затем с помощью `super(Main, self).__init__(root)` дополняется `__init__` класса Frame. Это означает, что вы как бы дописываете свой код, к тому, что уже есть у `Frame` в `__init__`. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-super/). А после идёт код, который вы дописываете(в частности вызываете функцию self.startUI(), в которой наполняете `Frame` кнопками, виджетами и т.д). Надеюсь хотя бы немного помог

Answer (score 2):

Класс `Frame` Является предком класса `Main`.Все созданные объекты класса `Main` будут обладать свойствами(атрибутами и методами) класса `Frame`:

```
class Main(Frame):
```

Инициализация класса `Main`:

```
def __init__(self, root):
```

Переопределение у Класса `Main` метода `__init__()`(который должен был работать также как у класса `Frame`):

```
super(Main, self).__init__(root)
```

При инициализации объекта `Main`, сработает метод `startUI()`. Именно этим и будет инициализация объектов класса `Main` отличаться от инициализации объектов класса `Frame`:

```
self.startUI()
```